# Iteration in Python loop is just repeating values

Tags: python, function, loops, linear-regression

I am trying to run multiple OLS models over a zip list. I have a list over products and geographies, so I created a regression function to use on the zip list. What I want to do is extract the coefficient value from each of these models and put it into my data frame. The problem is when I run my function and loop I just get repeated values.

```
# create lm function:
def lm_function(y_train, X_train):
    y_train = g2.iloc[0:,3]
    X_train = g2.iloc[0:,4]
    # Create Constant:
    X_train = sm.add_constant(X_train)
    models = sm.OLS(y_train,X_train).fit()
    return models

# create list:
prod_list = list(g2['Product'])
geo_list = list(g2['Geography'])

# zip the list together:
data = list(zip(prod_list, geo_list))

coef = []

for values in data:
    model_list = lm_function(g2.loc[(g2["Product"]==values[0]) & (g2["Geography"]==values[1])],g2.loc[(g2["Product"]==values[0]) & (g2["Geography"]==values[1])])
    # append the coef to the empty list:
    coef.append(model_list.params[1])
```

The output is just the first coefficient number of the first model repeated the whole time. Any thoughts?

Thanks!

[image: Repeated Values]

[image: Data print out]

Comment: It's probably worth putting in some print statements to see what `data` is and what each `values` is

Comment: The zip list "data" looks like it's printing fine. Here is a snip of it. You can see that it's doing the same product but changing the location.

Comment: Ah, I see the problem, you are overwriting `x_train` and `y_train` in `lm_function`. Remove those lines and it should work

Comment: @C_Z_ just want to make sure, remove the y_train = g2.iloc and the X_train from the lm function?

Comment: Yes, that's correct